# Java - Regex extract date from string

Tags: java, regex, date, extract

I need to extract date from this string:

BB inform: buy your tickect, final card number xxxx, $ 00,00, on 04/10, at 11:28. If you don't recognize call 40032 2412.

Also The full date 04/10/2015

The date pattern is dd/MM or dd/MM/yyyy

The code:

String mydata = "BB inform: buy your tickect, final card number xxxx, $ 00,00, on 04/10, at 11:28. If you don't recognize call 40032 2412.";

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(mydata);
```

Result:
m.matches() == false

Comment: Please post a piece of code of what you have tried so far, and where you failed

Comment: i'm sorry, i posted now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You can try with this regex :**

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}|\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(string);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

Its looking for a pattern DD/MM or then looking for a DD/MM/YYYY.

Check this [Link](https://regex101.com/r/pM3xX1/1)

Comment: It doesn't work. I guess it is because there is text before and after the date. if there is only date in the string this will work but not is my case

Comment: It worked . I copied your text and form the regex for it.

Comment: I can second that. I copied this code snippet and ran it against the OP's string, and it did return the date.

Comment: @MadushanPerera  man, do you know how i get the value after "$" ? And if the value is like $0000,00?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE); 
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));

        }
```

Pattern.MULTILINE ensures that it is searching the match of DD/MM or DD/MM/YYYY if it exist in the string