# Parse Date using DateTimeFormatter with extra chars

Tags: java, parsing, date

How can I parse a String date using DateTimeFormatter with extra chars..

Example: "My birthday is 2001-01-01 10:14:14"

Comment: does `My birthday is ` is static?

Comment: it may change..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Regex extract date from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923741/java-regex-extract-date-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your string using this pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "'My birthday is' uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

**Output**

```
2001-01-01T10:14:14
```

---

If your string is changed, then you should extract the datetime part using for example regex, and then parse the result, for example:

```
String newStr = str.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*?", "$1");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(newStr, formatter);
System.out.println(ldt);
```

Comment: great.. its working.. what does this mean: ".*?(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*?"

Comment: @Develofer It is a regex to extract the datetime part from your string, you can look at this [`.*?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*?`](https://regex101.com/r/RHWeAB/1)