# Java - Return date from a string (NOT converting a string to a date)

Tags: java

This isn't a request to convert a string to a date, I already know how to do that. I've tried googling and am only finding how to convert a date to a string.

The end goal is to show sheets that have a future date in their title.

The Sheets name is varied. The ones I am interested in will be in the format of: Codes Date (i.e. "Codes 11.01.21") There may be additional text at the start of the end though.

I have it filtering to only show sheets with the word "Codes" in them.

The part I am struggling with is how to get the date from the string. I'm assuming I need to use some form of regular expression to get the just the date part

```
List<com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Sheet> sheets = sp.getSheets();
        sheets.forEach(sheet -> {
            if(sheet.getProperties().getTitle().contains("Codes")) {
                System.out.println("Title: " + sheet.getProperties().getTitle());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Consider using `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: The issue is I don't know how to extract the date from the string. The string doesn't contain just the date

Comment: Read up on regex

Comment: In that case, a regular expression (or a simple substring if the date's position is fixed) should be enough to do the job.

Comment: Please keep your question short and simple. You said much about what you could do and only a few words about what you want to do. As far as I understand from all that text, you try to extract a string `dd.dd.dd` from a string with random text. You simply archieve this by using regular expressions. There are many examples in the internet. e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923741/java-regex-extract-date-from-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the regex to get your date from the input String, for the Date you added ("Codes 11.01.21") use this regex  \b(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}):

```
String data = "Codes 11.01.21";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: This is a Java question.  Your answer is not directly usable in Java.

Comment: @VGR he just asks about the regex!