# Find certain numbers in a String and add them in separate ints

Tags: java, string

I need a way to take specific "random" numbers from a string and put them each in separate int variables.
For example this string cannot/shouldnt be changed:
`String date = "59598 22-01-19 22:46:32 00 0 0  66.2 UTC(NIST) * ";`

I need these three numbers in separet ints "22-01-19".
So one int would be called "day" and it holds the number 19, another int is called "month" and it holds the number 1, another int called "year" and it holds the number 22.

This is what it would look like:

```
String date = "59598 22-01-19 22:46:32 00 0 0  66.2 UTC(NIST) * ";
int day = 0;
int month = 0;
int year = 0;

//(method for finding these numbers and putting them into the separate int variables)

System.out.println(year+" "+month+" "+day);
```

Thank you in advance!

Note: I did not find a solution that explained this well enough for me to understand it, I apologize if there already excists a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split `date` twice to get a list of the date

```java
String date = "59598 22-01-19 22:46:32 00 0 0  66.2 UTC(NIST) * ";
String[] splittedDate = date.split(" ")[1].split("-");

int day = Integer.valueOf(splittedDate[2]);
int month = Integer.valueOf(splittedDate[1]);
int year = Integer.valueOf(splittedDate[0]);

//(method for finding these numbers and putting them into the separate int variables)

System.out.println(year+" "+month+" "+day);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the date (those specific values) from the String. You could use regular expressions (regex) to extract this.
Have a look at this solution which is similar to what you want to achieve
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33924024/6099890

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the date is always the second token, you can do it like so.

- split the string on spaces, and use the second token
- define a formatter to parse the date assigning to a `LocalDate` instance.
- then pull extract the values
- you can use those extractions to re-format the date
- or you can use the formatter

```
String date = "59598 22-01-19 22:46:32 00 0 0  66.2 UTC(NIST) * ";

String[] tokens = date.split("\\s+", 3);
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(("dd-MM-y"));
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(tokens[1], dtf);

int day = ld.getDayOfMonth();
int year = ld.getYear();
int month = ld.getMonthValue();

System.out.printf("%02d-%02d-%02d%n", day, month, year);
System.out.println(ld.format(dtf));
```

prints

```
22-01-19
22-01-19
```

For more info, check out the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.  If you are going to be parsing or manipulating date/time objects, this is an essential class to know.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I do agree that this works but isnt all that pretty uneccecary for what I'm trying to accomplish? The String I was manipulating is technically just a normal String so why not use the method that Marcos Blandim answered with?

Also that's an extra import. Generally you would want as few imports as possible right?

Comment: I simply gave an alternative example.   But my very last sentence is still valid,

Comment: Yes, this is true. Thank you again. :)